# javascript, will it be ignored if the value is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if I understand this javascript,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo" style="width: 80px; height: 12px;">test</div>

<script>

var obj = {moduleId:"demo"};

   var ret = changeElementHeight(obj)
   console.log(ret)

function changeElementHeight(t) {
                            var o = t.moduleId
                              , s = o && document.getElementById(o);
                            
                            var n = void 0
                              , i = void 0
                              , r = void 0 === a || a
                              , l = t.viewHeight
                              , d = t.viewWidth
                              , c = t.height
                              , u = t.width

                            c && (n = parseInt(c, 10),
                            void 0 !== l && (n = n * 120 / parseInt(l, 10))),
                            u && (i = parseInt(u, 10),
                            void 0 !== d && (i = i * 200 / parseInt(d, 10))),
                            
                            // will this Object.assign(); be called, or because the 'n' and 'i' are undefined, so that it is called but no effect ??? 

                            Object.assign(s.style, {
                                height: n + "px",
                                width: i && i + "px" || "auto"
                            });

                            var h = s.getBoundingClientRect()
                            var x = {
                                bottom: h.bottom,
                                height: h.height,
                                left: h.left,
                                right: h.right,
                                top: h.top,
                                width: h.width
                            };
                            return x
                        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when pass in json does not have the width, height etc., will this

```
Object.assign(s.style, {
                                height: n + "px",
                                width: i && i + "px" || "auto"
                            });
```

be called to update the div's style (at this moment n and i are undefined)?

seems the div's width does get affected but not height:

```
{bottom: 38, height: 12, left: 8, right: 972, top: 26, width: 964}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have `undefined` variables, that will throw an error in your console and no, the code will not continue to execute.

However, if the variables are defined, but empty strings, the code will exectue and process at that time, but if `n` is `""`, then you'll attempt to set the `height` to `px`, which is not a valid value, so it is ignored (bad CSS doesn't throw errors) and the previous value is continued to be used.

Here's a more simplified example:

```js
document.querySelector("div").style.height = "" + "px"; // no error, no effect
document.querySelector("div").style.width = "200px"; // works
```

```css
div { 
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#808080;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```